# .htaccess Rewrite Rule based on numeric value

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to do a rewrite-rule at htaccess. The following URL should be rewrited:

http://www.website.com/folder/subfolder/subsub/product-p00000

I'd like to make a rewrite-URL that recognizes the "-p" and then a numeric value. How do I make this rule? I have the following, but not sure how to add the numeric value to it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-p(.*)/?$ /file.php?folder=$1&subfolder=$2&subsub=$3&product=$4&id=$5
```

However, in the case of the following URL this goes wrong ofcourse:

http://www.website.com/folder/subfolder/subsub/product-product

How do I add the condition that the URL should end on "-p" followed by a numeric value?

Comment: **p([0-9]+)** should work.